# i have a problem in adding faker to node.fs

Tags: node.js, faker

this is the error:

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:361
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'c:\Users\moham\node_modules\faker\index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
at tryPackage (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:353:19)
at Function.Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:566:18)
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:919:27)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
at Object. (c:\Users\moham\Desktop\test\test:1:13)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32) {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
path: 'c:\Users\moham\node_modules\faker\package.json',
requestPath: 'faker'
}

this is the code:

var faker = require('faker');

console.log(faker.internet.email());

console.log(faker.date.past());

console.log(faker.address.city());

and I had installed the faker my the code:
npm install faker

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRk0U.png)

Answer (score 1):

The last version of faker is 6.6.6. There is a curious story behind it but we leave it for your free time discovery.
Quick fix is to downgrade version of the `faker`.
Firstly uninstall current version with `npm unistall faker` then run `npm i faker@5.5.3` to install last working version of the package

Comment: That works, but even better would be migrating to the new official fork [@faker-js/faker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@faker-js/faker)